# Write a Gradle Plugin that reacts to multiple plugins

Tags: gradle, plugins, kotlin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to write a new Gradle plugin which requires the application of two plugins: either `java` or `java-library`, or `maven-publish`. I am writing the plugin in Kotlin.

I can easily, following the [Gradle guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20190312175905/https://guides.gradle.org/implementing-gradle-plugins/), make the plugin react to a single plugin application:

```
project.plugins.withType(MavenPublishPlugin::class.java) {
    // My stuff
}
```

But I can't do the same for requiring two plugin applications:

```
project.plugins.withType(JavaPlugin::class.java) {
    project.plugins.withType(MavenPublishPlugin::class.java) {
        // My stuff
    }
}
```

In the second case, launching with:

### Case 1: as expected

```
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("maven-publish")
    id("org.danilopianini.publish-on-central")
}
```

runs the plugin as expected

### Case 2: non applied, as expected

using:

```
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("org.danilopianini.publish-on-central")
}
```

does not apply the plugin, as expected

### Case 3: applied, it should have not been

but, finally:

```
plugins {
    id("maven-publish")
    id("org.danilopianini.publish-on-central")
}
```

tries to apply the plugin and fails with:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/tmp/junit876726632157783854/build.gradle.kts' line: 1

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.danilopianini.publish-on-central']
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.danilopianini.publish-on-central']
   > SoftwareComponentInternal with name 'java' not found.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.InvalidPluginException: An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.danilopianini.publish-on-central']
[cut]
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.danilopianini.publish-on-central']
    ... 128 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownDomainObjectException: SoftwareComponentInternal with name 'java' not found.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.createNotFoundException(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:489)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.getByName(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:323)
```

Which looks to me as an attempt to apply the plugin regardless the fact that the Java plugin was not applied.

Do you know any way to configure a plugin to react to multiple plugin applications?